# Print parameters and scores GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, printf, grid-search

I can't figure out why I can't print all the scores with the different parameters in GridSearchCV.

Code:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

pipe_svm = Pipeline([
    ('sc', StandardScaler()),
    ('SVM', SVC())
    ])

params_svm = {'SVM__C': np.logspace(-2, 10, 13),
              'SVM__kernel': ['rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid']}

search_svm = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_svm,
                      param_grid=params_svm,
                      cv = 5,
                      return_train_score=True)

search_svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(search_svm.best_score_)
print(search_svm.best_params_)
```

Output:

```
0.9004240532229588
{'SVM__C': 1.0, 'SVM__kernel': 'rbf'}
```

This is great, but I would like to print all the different scores with the given parameters (to compare it with the best). Below is what I've tried, it's lacking a lot of different parameters combinations with the respective score.

Code:

```
scores_svm = search_svm.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
for score, C, kernel in zip(scores_svm, np.logspace(-2, 10, 13), ['rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid']):
    print(f"{C, kernel}: {score:.10f}")
```

Output:

```
0.01, rbf: 0.8500203678
0.1, poly: 0.6785667684
1.0, sigmoid: 0.8364788196
```

Desired output would include all C values in `np.logspace(-2, 10, 13)` with the different kernel and assign the corresponding score. Something like this:

```
0.001, rbf: corresponding score
0.01, rbf: corresponding score
1.0, rbf: corresponding score
10.0, rbf: corresponding score
.
.
.
```

And so on

Comment: Just load `cv_results_` into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

This should be :

```
kernels = ['rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid']
C = np.logspace(-2, 10, 13)
for idx, kernel in enumerate(kernels):
    for score, c in (zip(scores_svm[idx*len(C): (idx+1)*len(C)], C)):
        print(f"{c, kernel}: {score:.10f}")
```

---

Actually `len(scores_svm)` is `13*n` and that of `len(np.logspace(-2, 10, 13))` is `13`.

How you can zip them together when they have different length. That's why on zipping them together you are getting only three of them. as minimum len is 3 inside the zip.

**Sample Code:**

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X_train = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 3]])
y_train = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1])
pipe_svm = Pipeline([
    ('sc', StandardScaler()),
    ('SVM', SVC())
    ])

params_svm = {'SVM__C': np.logspace(-2, 10, 13),
              'SVM__kernel': ['rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid']}

search_svm = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_svm,
                      param_grid=params_svm,
                      cv = 2,
                      return_train_score=True)

search_svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(search_svm.best_score_)
print(search_svm.best_params_)

# 0.41666666666666663
# {'SVM__C': 0.01, 'SVM__kernel': 'rbf'}
```

---

```
scores_svm = search_svm.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
for score, C, kernel in zip(scores_svm, np.logspace(-2, 10, 13), ['rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid']):
    print(f"{C, kernel}: {score:.10f}")
```

---

```
(0.01, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(0.1, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(1.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(10.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(100.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(1000.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(10000.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(100000.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(1000000.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(10000000.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(100000000.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(1000000000.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(10000000000.0, 'rbf'): 0.4166666667
(0.01, 'poly'): 0.4166666667
(0.1, 'poly'): 0.4166666667
(1.0, 'poly'): 0.4166666667
.
.
.
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I intended, thank you. However now I can't unseen the fact that my best parameters don't match with the list. `search_svm.best_params_` selects `(C=1.0, 'rbf')` and with the given code apparently the best `(C=10000.0, 'rbf')`

Comment: May be the best parameter have been taken using some other metric than `'mean_test_score'`.

Comment: It is using `'mean_test_score'`. The main question shows a SCV model, I am using other models too (logistic reg and DTC) and the your answer worked perfectly, just not sure why not on this SVC.

Comment: Are they having the same score? Can you post score for those two values.

Comment: DTC:
`print(search_decsT.best_score_)` shows `0.8591172612157564`
`print(search_decsT.best_params_)` shows `{'decsT__criterion': 'gini', 'decsT__max_depth': 8}`
Adapting your answer for this scenario:
`(7, 'gini'): 0.8576808259
(8, 'gini'): 0.8591172612
(9, 'gini'): 0.8570654413
.
.
.`

Which definitely matches, same for the logistic reg.

This is the best score of SVC `0.9004240532229588` which actually matches `(10000.0, 'rbf'): 0.9004240532` from your answer instead of C=1.

Comment: what about values for svc?

Comment: This is the best score of SVC `0.9004240532229588` which actually matches `(10000.0, 'rbf'): 0.9004240532` from your answer instead of C=1 according to `print(search_svm.best_params_)` showing `{'SVM__C': 1.0, 'SVM__kernel': 'rbf'}`

Comment: `(1.0, 'rbf'): 0.8364788196`

Comment: May be there is problem with the code I provided you.  this line `scores_svm[idx*len(C): (idx+1)*len(C)]` . Can you debug and see.  Because I think while printing you are getting different valuet. because of the mistake in the code. If not due to code, then try creating an issue in github about that.  Have to go now. It's too late for me. gn :) I will look into it in the morning.

Comment: I am kind of new to programming, don't know how to debug. But why would it work with other models and just not with this one?

Comment: I guess it's better to raise an issue on github. Because I myself doesn't have answer for this . All I can think of ordering of kernels. Like we are printing in our own order of kernels. Which value to which kernels if we can find that. Then it will solve this problem.